# Spring Data JPA - findAllBy query checks for null?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) shows that `findByLastnameAndFirstname` equals to `where x.lastname = ?1 and x.firstname = ?2`.

We know that in sql `= NULL` is always false. You have to use `IS NULL`.

Let's say we have an entry `firstname = "First"` and `lastname IS NULL`. I call this `findByLastnameAndFirstname(null, "First")`. I suppose it would return me empty result because `= NULL` is always false. However from my testing, it returned the entry.

Why? Does Spring Data JPA do something magically internally?

If I have to write a custom query for this, it would be something like `:lastname IS NULL and lastname IS NULL or lastname = :lastname`. Easier way to write such custom query with Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Enable SQL logging, and you'll know what SQL query is being generated and executed.

Answer (score 0):

This query always returns a `List`. If no results, this list is an **empty** list (in Hibernate, if you return an `SingleResult` not `ResultList` then Hibernate throws `NoResultException`).

In your case, I guess using `findByLastnameIsNullAndFirstname(String firstname)`.